# apache default download/page rate limit

Tags: php, apache, download, limit, rate

I got this code on a apache webserver, to do speed test.

My server is located at Hetzner.de, but i can only get download speed at about 20mbit.

Is there a default limit with apache, or php. I should get around 100 mbit

```
if ($_GET['s']){
    $kb = $_GET['s'];
    for($x=0;$x<$kb;$x++){
        echo str_pad('', 1024, '.');
        echo "\n";
        flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Weclome to StackOverflow! I don't know much about `php`, but I don't think your speed test can provide accurate results. Have you tried a simple binary file over http without using `php`? There seem too much layers inbetween you server and your client.  `php` has to be run, the output has put through buffers and passed on later on to the webserver,..

Comment: This php script can generate files at all size's, if i make a 10mb file, and then save it as a file.html, it have the same download speed. If i put a image on the server size 10mb, i can download at my internet speed etc. 100mbit, but php/html max 20mbit.